# Queue management project - Recommendations

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, webforms, queue

I would like to develop a Patient Queue management system with online booking.

In this case there are options to generate queue tokens for various departments. For example dept A will have tokens from A1,A2,A3 etc. And dept B have tokens from B1,B2,B3 etc.

At the time of calling a token if patient is not available then that token should be added after next 3 tokens.

Other than this, there is an online module where a patient can book a specific time slot. Online booked tokens should be inserted in between the normal tokens on specific time.

considering these all requirements can anyone suggest a better solution. Is C# queue will be a better solution? or any other ideas/suggestions?

Edit

I will go for on site booking with sql table.

is there any easy way to manage the sequence if there is a token on hold. for example

```
BookingID   SeqNo
A1           1
A2           2
A3           3
A4           4
A5           5
A6           6
```

Now when token A3 on hold i want to put him after 3 tokens. then table will be

```
BookingID   SeqNo
    A1           1
    A2           2
    A3           6
    A4           3
    A5           4
    A6           5
```

Thank you

Comment: Consider operating this system. How many computers? Network? Database? What if the machine restarts? How will the receptionist insert an emergency ticket? Or remove a cancelled one? What if a department closes for the day? Think this through... Once you have done that, go out and find several different technologies and see how closely they match your needs, and the effort involved in making them fit if they fall short. Then if you are still stuck come back with a specific question.

Comment: @Kain0_0 i will have 3 logins. Admin, Counter Officer, Customer Support. I will have one main screen to display all tokens and counters. another small screen to show token for each counter. I prefer to use database. I will choose ASP.net webforms and SQL Server

Comment: @SachuMine: You're not responding to the questions on the functional needs of the application, whic strongly suggests that you have not properly analyzed the customer needs. When you have done so, it's purely a matter of checking which technology fits best with your requirements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Design issue

In reality you have two very different booking processes with different rules:

- Online, it’s fixed hour
- On site, it’s relative order (first arrived, first served)

Mixing both in a single queue is risky.  Because inserting a fixed-hour appointment forces you to make prediction that ignore the queue dynamics.

For example:

- If it’s time `t0` now, and fixed hour appointment is at `t1`, you’d need to insert the fixed appointment in `trunc((t1-t0)/t)` position, `t` being the average duration of an appointment.
- First, what do you do if there are not enough tickets waiting ?
- Now suppose it went well, but that a ticket holder doesn’t show up. For example one or two persons before the fixed appointment. Then the whole timing is shifted: the fixed appointment will be called `t` minutes too early. If he’s not there, when his ticket is picked from the queue it's a no-show and he’ll be pushed-back 3 tickets later. When he’ll finally arrive, he’ll have to wait `2t`, and will be angry because despite advanced booking and timely arrival he had to wait. If `t` is 20 minutes, it can be a real annoyance.

More robust approach would be design your software to manage each process according to its rules.  I see two main approaches:

- You could to use two queues.  The fixed-appointment queue will always be examined first, to look if it's time for the next fixed point appointment.  By the way, the fixed point queue would rather be an ordered list, so that new appointments can be inserted according to their time.
- Or you could process fixed appointments according to calendar and process queued tickets only outside the booked slots.

### To queue or not to queue ?

Now, regardless of how the chose design, you'll have at least one "queue", with the following possibilities to implement it:

- you may use a WAITING table in a database. In this scenario, you'd create an entry in the table for each new ticket.  The entry shall have a unique id (sequential ticket number), and a sequence number that is the order in the queue (and that you can renumber when you have to shift no-shows)
- you may alternatively use a `queue<ticket>` in memory. There are some practical issues in this approach:

  - first, you are only able to enqueue and dequeue in the right order. So you cannot insert a dequeud ticket 3 places later, but only enqueue it at the end.
  - second, memory queues are no persistent.  So you need to decide what to do at the end of the day: do you save the serialized queue to a file to reload and deserialize the next day ? Or do you restart anew every day ? And what if  you have to restart in the middle if the day (system crash, mandatory update, etc...) : panic ? One approach could be to logg the different queuing events so that you may reconstruct a queue after a crash.

The database approach seems safer to me.  If you’d go for the in-memory approach, you’d be advised to look for a more flexible container than the queue, to cope with you no-show policy.

---

### Edit: implementation

*First, thank you for your feedack on this answer and about your choice. I'll answer hereafter your questions regarding the implementation of the selected DB approach.*

#### Alternative 1: auto-increment

The easiest approach would be to use the [autoincrement](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_autoincrement.asp) feature of the DBMS that you will use.  This feature lets the DB generate a unique sequential id for a table.  The problem is that this feature can only manage a single sequence per table and without any prefix.  If you take this approach your table would look like this:

```
BookingId     QueueId      SeqNo
   1             A           1
   2             A           2
   3             A           3
   4             B           1       // You need to select by QueueId
   5             A           4
   6             A           5
   7             A           6
```

This is the easiest implementation, since the DB takes care of the id increment.  The inconvenience is that the ticket number will be sequential across all queues. This means that user with ticket 4 doesn't know that he is the first in the B queue.  But this is not a real problem, because you can select the entries by queue, and manage the order relatively to the relevant queue.

#### Alternative 2: manual increment

In this scenario, you'd use an sequence table, in addition to the queuing table that you describe:

```
QueueId  NextCounter
   A          7 
   B          3
   C        125
```

In this case when you'd add a ticket, you'd use the counter and update it to create ticket A7.  Unfortunately, this is very tricky if you have several processes sharing the database, because several processes could try ton compute a new sequence number and obtain the same (non-unique) result, causing some insertions to fail.  There are plenty of questions here and on SO about this kind of issue, that you can master with transaction management but stays tricky.

Note that it would nevertheless be safer to keep the `QueueId` and `BookingId` in two different fields (that are combined to serve as primary keu).

#### Alternative 3: in memory counter

Another approach would be to store a map or an array in memory of your back-end process.  The map is initialised wHen the process starts: the DB is querried for the largest `BookingId` for each queue.  You'd manage the sequence of each queue in memory.

This works only if there is a unique back-end process.

#### Other alternatives

There are several other alternatives/combinations possible.  If needed, you may have a look here (I think I have already seen related questions) and if needed ask a new, more specialised question.

Comment: Thank you so much.. I have decided to go for on site booking (FCFS) and sql db tables. as you said i will create waiting table with uid and seq number.

Comment: I have edited the question. can you please help

Comment: You could go for an [autoincrement](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_autoincrement.asp) but it’s one sequence shared for all queues, which means the queue id “A” should be in another field. Alternatively, you can keep a table with the latest number for each queue and manage it in a transaction (a little more tricky). Finally, if you have only one backend service that exclusively uses the db, you could manage it in memory (at service startup, read the latest number in db)

Comment: I didnt get you sorry. Do you mean to create a table say Latest and kepp the latest id? in our case its A6? Can you help with an example

Comment: @SachuMine I have edited my answer.  Hope this help :-)

Comment: thank you. I got you, and thank you for your valuable time.. But the case which i asked is something different. As per your first suggestion, how we can achieve hold coupens. is there any common procedure to achieve this

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58115788/sequential-token-management-in-sql-server